# Бесконечный await Task в определенном месте

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

Я попытался сделать это в net fiddle, для более наглядного примера, но не смог, поэтому постараюсь описать проблему тут, со вставками кода.

В Крации что происходит: Запускается приложение(wpf mvvm), следовательно запускается конструктор `ViewModel` начального окна. В конструкторе создается экземпляр(объект) класса таймера(`FilmTimer`)

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            FilmTimer timer = new FilmTimer();
            ...
        }
```

В котором находится поле с парсером фильма(`FilmParser`)

```
class FilmTimer
    {
      private FilmParser _filmParser = new FilmParser();
      ....
    }
```

В `FilmParser` мы приходим к singleton классу `httpclient`

```
public class FilmParser
    {
        private SiteFilmsHttp siteHttp = SiteFilmsHttp.GetInstance();
        ....
    }
```

В `SiteFilmsHttp` происходит создание объекта по поиску сайта(фабрика) и установка базовых загловков, следовательно и найденного сайта в `BaseAdress`.

```
private static readonly SiteFilmsHttp _instance = new SiteFilmsHttp();

        public SiteFilmsHttp()
        {
            SetSiteHeaders().Wait();
        }
        private async Task SetSiteHeaders()
        {
            SiteSearcherFabric factory = new SiteSearcherFabric();
            var searcher = await factory.CreateSiteSearcherAsync();

            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(searcher.WorkingLinks.First());
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = Client.BaseAddress.Host;
        }
```

И в итоге, после вызова `var searcher = await factory.CreateSiteSearcherAsync();`
все асинхронные операции находящийся в этом методе, не выполняются и превращаются в бесконечные задачи.

Внутри `await factory.CreateSiteSearcherAsync();`
Это примеры, которые я поставил для проверки, и они не прошли

```
    public class SiteFabric
    {
        public async Task<ISearcher> CreateSiteSearcherAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { });
            var vlad = await PublicHttp.GetInstance().Client.GetAsync("https://tv.lordfilm.black/");
        }
    ....
    }
```

После первого `await` бесконечная задача и окно следовательно не открывается.

Тесты:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task Check_site_performance()
        {
            SiteFilmsHttp siteFilmsHttp = SiteFilmsHttp.GetInstance();

            string html = await siteFilmsHttp.Client.GetStringAsync(siteFilmsHttp.Client.BaseAddress);

            Assert.IsNotNull(html);
        }
```

Все в тестах прекрасно отрабатывается.

Как мне кажется ошибка выше по уровню `FilmParser`, `FilmTimer`

Единственное что помогло решить ошибку.
Перенести создание объекта в метод, который будет потом вызываться

```
private SiteFilmsHttp siteHttp;

public void SomeMethod()
{
   siteHttp = SiteFilmsHttp.GetInstance();
}
```

И все работает.
Но я хочу сделать это без костылей и узнать в чем ошибка, чтобы потом не допустить её

Comment: Подозреваю, проблема тут `SetSiteHeaders().Wait();`, если убрать wait и все заработает, то вы ловите дедлок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> все асинхронные операции находящийся в этом методе, не выполняются и превращаются в бесконечные задачи.

Это называется дедлок (deadlock). Почитаете про это явление - поймете, что его вызвало. А если быть точнее - вот это.

```
SetSiteHeaders().Wait();
```

Никогда не блокируйте поток таском. Тогда и дедлоков не будет. Если уж начали асинхронный код писать - пишите до конца.

Сделайте инициализацию синглтона асинхронной.

```
private static SiteFilmsHttp _instance;
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private SiteFilmsHttp() { } // закрываем конструктор от внешнего мира

public static async Task<SiteFilmsHttp> GetInstanceAsync()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // семафор не позволит создать 2 экземпляра
        try
        {
            if (_instance != null)
                return _instance;
            var instance = new SiteFilmsHttp();
            await instance.SetSiteHeaders().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _instance = instance;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

```
public async Task<ISearcher> CreateSiteSearcherAsync()
{
    var task = SiteFilmsHttp.GetInstanceAsync();
    var instance = task.IsCompleted ? task.Result : await task;
    var vlad = await instance.Client.GetAsync("https://tv.lordfilm.black/");
}
```

Это всё я налету придумал, возможно существует более изящное решение.